# Fast hashing of 32 bit values to between 0 and 254 inclusive

Tags: c, hash, opencl, vectorization

I'm looking for a fast way in C to hash numbers 32-bit numbers more or less uniformly between 0 and 254.  255 is reserved for a special purpose.

As an added constraint, I'm looking for a method that would map well to being used with ISA-specific vector intrinsics or to a language like OpenCL or CUDA without introducing control flow divergence between the vector lanes/threads.

Ordinarily, I would just use the following code to hash the number between 0 and 255, as this is just a fast way of doing x mod 256.

```
inline uint8_t hash(uint32_t x){  return x & 255; }
```

I could just give in and use the following:

```
inline uint8_t hash(uint32_t x){  return x % 255; }
```

However, this solution seems unimaginative and unlikely to be the highest performing solution.  I found code at this site (http://homepage.cs.uiowa.edu/~jones/bcd/mod.shtml#exmod15) that appears to provide a reasonable solution for scalar code and have inserted it here for your convenience.

```
uint32_t mod255( uint32_t a ) {
  a = (a >> 16) + (a & 0xFFFF); /* sum base 2**16 digits */
  a = (a >>  8) + (a & 0xFF);   /* sum base 2**8 digits */
  if (a < 255) return a;
  if (a < (2 * 255)) return a - 255;
  return a - (2 * 255);
}
```

I see two potential performance issues with this code:

1. The large number of if statements makes me question how easy it will be for a compiler or human :) to effectively vectorize the code without leading to control flow divergence within a warp/wavefront on a SIMT architecture or vectorized execution on a multicore CPU.  If such divergence does occur, it will reduce parallel efficiency, as the divergent paths will have to be run in series.
2. It looks like it could be troublesome for a branch predictor (not applicable on common GPU architectures) as the code path that executes depends on the value of the input. Therefore, if there is a mix of small and large values interspersed with one another, this code will likely sacrifice some performance due to a moderate number of branch mispredictions.

Any recommendations on alternatives that I could use are most welcome.  Alternatively, let me know if what I am asking for is unreasonable.

Comment: If your input is uniformly between 0 and 254, why do you think a hash would help? You've already got perfect input.

Comment: I would definitely opt for a branchless solution.  Without knowing more about the numbers you are hashing, you could consider some simple bitwise combinations, such as `((byte0 ^ byte2) + (byte1 ^ byte3)) % 255`

Comment: I would highly recommend doing the naive approach (`x%255`) and measuring performance _before_ optimizing this. If computing this hash is all you are doing, then this is most likely a memory-bound operation. You should measure throughput against theoretical maximum throughput. If you can get 80-90% throughput, it's not worth optimizing further. Realistically if you are doing any interesting computation on top of this, then this is likely a very small part of your runtime, even with naive implementation.

Comment: Also, it's unlikely that the same optimizations work equally well on all target platforms. If this hashing is _really_ performance critical, then you will need to optimize for each platform.

Comment: Idea: Fold using `^` to a fast smallish integer size and then `%`   `(uint16_t)(x >> 16 ^ x) %255`,

Comment: [Compute modulus division by `(1 << s) - 1` (in parallel) without a division operator](https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ModulusDivision)

Comment: As illustrated in the link above, you can eliminate the conditional stuff by doing a couple of extra rounds of `a = (a >>  8) + (a & 0xFF)`, and then mapping 255 back down to zero, which I'm sure should be handled competently by the GPU and the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just do this:

```
uchar fast_mod255( uint a32 ) {
  ushort a16 = (a32 >> 16) + (a32 & 0xFFFF); /* sum base 2**16 digits */
  uchar a8 = (a16 >>  8) + (a16 & 0xFF);   /* sum base 2**8 digits */
  return (a8 % 255);
}
```

Another option is to just do:

```
uchar fast_mod255( uchar4 a ) {
  return (dot(a) % 255); // or   return (distance(a) % 255);
}
```

GPUs are very efficient in computing the distances and dot products, even in 4 dimensions. And it is a valid way of hashing as well. Dsicarding the overflowed values.

---

No branching, and a clever compiler can even optimize it out. Or do you really need that values that fall in the 255 zone have a scattered pattern instead of 1?

Answer (score 3):

The "`if` statements on GPU kill performance" is a popular misconception which desperately wants to live on, it seems.

> The large number of if statements makes me question how easy it will
>   be for a compiler or human :) to vectorize the code.

First of all I wouldn't consider 2 `if` statements a "large number of `if` statements", and those are so short and trivial that I'm willing to bet the compiler will turn them into branchless conditional moves or predicated instructions. There will be no performance penalty at all. (Do check the generated assembly, however).

> It looks like it could be troublesome for a branch predictor as the code path that executes depends on the value of the input. Therefore, if there is a mix of small and large values interspersed with one another, this code will likely sacrifice some performance due to a moderate number of branch mispredictions.

Current GPUs do not have branch predictors. Note however that depending on the underlying hardware, operation on integers (and notably shifting) may be quite costly.

Comment: You are correct that divergence between warps is not a performance pitfall in GPGPU programming.


I will check the assembly.  There is a good chance that I am underestimating the optimization abilities of the compiler.


Thanks for the note on branch predictors in GPUs.  I've updated my question to include this information.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to answer my own question because over the last 2 years I have seen ways to get around a slow integer divide instruction.  The easiest way is to make the integer a compile-time constant.  Any decent modern compiler should replace the integer divide with an equivalent set of other instructions with typically higher throughput (how many such instructions can be retired per cycle) and reduced latency (how many cycles it takes the instruction to execute).  If you're curious, check out Hacker's Delight (an excellent book on low-level computer arithmetic).

I wanted to share another finding, which I found on Daniel Lemire's blog ([located here)](https://lemire.me/blog/2016/06/27/a-fast-alternative-to-the-modulo-reduction/).  The code that follows doesn't compute mod 255 but does something similar, which is equally useful in a number of applications and much faster.

Suppose that you have a set of numbers S that are uniformly randomly picked from the range 0 to 2^k - 1 inclusive, where k >= 0.  In this case, if you care only about mapping numbers roughly uniformly from 0 to 254 inclusive, you may do the following:

For each number n in a set S, you may map n to one of the 255 candidate values by multiplying n by 255 and then arithmetically shifting the result to the right by k digits.

Here is the function that you call on each n for a fixed value of k:

```
int map_to_0_to_254(int n, int k){
  return (n * 255) >> k;
}
```

As an example, if the values for the argument n range uniformly randomly from 0 to 4095 (2^12 - 1), 
then map_to_0_254(n, 12) will return a value in the range 0 to 254 inclusive.

Here is a more general templated version in C++ for mapping to range from 0 to range_size - 1 inclusive:

```
template<typename T>
T map_to_0_to_range_size_minus_1(T n, T range_size, T k){
  return (n * range_size) >> k;
}
```

REMEMBER that this code assumes that the inputs for n are roughly uniformly randomly distributed between 0 and 2^k - 1 inclusive.  If that property holds, then the outputs will be roughly uniformly distributed between 0 and range_size - 1 inclusive.  The larger 2^k is relative to range_size, the more uniform the mapping will be for a fixed set of inputs.

**Why This is Useful**

This approach has applications to computing hash functions for hash tables where the number of bins is not a power of 2.  Those operations would ordinarily require a long-latency integer divide instruction, which is often an order of magnitude slower to execute than an integer multiply, because you often do not know the number of bins in the hash table at compile time.